# Does android kill all components of a process?

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

As is well documented that to manage the memory, android system kills those activities which haven't been in foreground for long(or based on other criteria). As an activity instance is part of an app process,so would android kill all other components in that process?

And if yes, it brings to mind another question. Suppose activity on foreground is currently using a component from another app process, and meanwhile android decides to kill components in that process, won't it adversely impact functioning of foreground activity.

Answer (score 0):

In general, Android does not kill components. It usually just kills off entire processes (this is easier and more efficient). And yes, Android will kill background processes at any time for any reason. Your app needs to be able to cope with this behaviour.

Android does not kill components that are in the foreground.

What do you mean by "activity in foreground is currently using a component from another app process"? Please give an example.

Comment: Thanks for inputs.

Comment: Thanks for inputs.

I meant this:Suppose an activity ActA from application AppA is at foreground.Now user moves to another application AppB,so pushing activity ActA to background. Now activity ActB of AppB is in foreground, and it launches an implicit intent which android OS dispatches to a component CompA from AppA, and the component starts working in background. Meanwhile android decides to kill ActA, so it would kill all components from AppA. Won't it cause killing of CompA too whiLe its still working for ActB?

Comment: If ActB of AppB launches an implicit `Intent` which starts an `Activity` from AppA, that `Activity` will be in the foreground. It does not "start working in the background". Android will not kill `ActA` because that application is in the foreground.

Comment: ActB can also launch an implicit intent to launch a non-activity component of AppA,like some background service.

Comment: In that case, ActB would be in the foreground and the `Service` in AppA would be active. Android usually doesn't kill active components unless it has a reason.  However, even though these components depend on each other, Android doesn't really recognize this kind of dependency. An `Activity` can start a `Service` and this is all asynchronous (unless the `Activity` is bound to the `Service`), so the coupling is very weak. And, as I said before, Android can kill any background process at any time for any reason. Your app needs to be able to handle that in any case.

Comment: Thanks David for your valuable inputs.